# Issue with multiple DataTriggers bound to same VM property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have ran into an issue when more than one DataTriggers are bound to the same ViewModel property. After investigation, I have noticed that always the last one wins. How can I overcome the problem? Thanks

```html
          <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowGrid}" Value="false">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowGrid}" Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="50"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
```

BTW, this works fine:

```html
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowGrid}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowGrid}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
```

So, it is got to be storyboard related, any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard's FillBehavior defaults to HoldEnd, change it to `FillBehavior=Stop`

The default behavior is to keep the last values of a Storyboard set, tell it to reset them after it completed.

**Edit**

Ok now I understand what you want. You've to use DataTrigger.ExitActions:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowGrid}" Value="true">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="50"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Just tried it and it seems to do what you want. Don't forget to remove the other DataTrigger.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. While your suggestion partially works (not intended behavior), this does not resolve my issue. I have two buttons (Show and Hide). Once 'Show is clicked, command is being executed, property in ViewModel is being changed and then DataTrigger is executed (slides down grid and holds). Same happens on the other button, obviously bool property is set to opposite value (slides back grid and holds). I am close, but still not there. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The only way I was able to achieve intended behaviors it is to have events attached to the two buttons, and on each event in code behind I will update height of the grid. This works fine, but I would like to accomplish this purely with XAML, is there a way. Thanks. It is worth to note that previously mentioned 'FillBehavior=Stop' is crucial here to make it work.

Comment: The solution I have figure out to work in comment above is not the best option. It fails to work under one scenario. Need to figure out how to make it work with pure XAML